# Android studio tabedlayout

Tags: android, kotlin

> Type mismatch offered  type is classname but `Fragment?` was expected

This error show up in the inner class `SectionPageAdapter` in `MainActivity` specifc in the **funcation** `getItem`

Comment: The error (Type mismatch inferrd type is myclassname but Fragment? was expected )

Comment: Could you please provide some code and a bit more context.

Comment: May be issue with SupportFragment and Fragment... Please add the code